# Ocillate function between two values javascript

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry

I need to have a growing and decreasing circle in made in javascript.
My idea is to use a div with

```
border-radius : 50%
```

To get a circle. I need to make it scale from 0.2 to 1 every [x] seconds .

Like It grows from 0.2 to 1 in 5 seconds, then it decreases from 1 to 0.2 in5 seconds too. THen the movement starts again.
I think i have to use sin or cos functions but i don't know how to get this interval depending on time.

I need it to be coupled with a javascript timing function, so that when i satr a timer, the animation begins, and when I pause it it pauses the animation.

Thanks for advice !

Comment: I'd look at using classes and CSS animations or chaining callbacks so that when the function is finished all processing it calls itself with an inverse argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with CSS3 animations. Look at this example and change it until it does exactly how you want it.

```css
#circle {
    -webkit-animation: oscillate 10s infinite;
    animation: oscillate 10s infinite;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes oscillate {
    0%   { border-radius: 20%;  }
    50%  { border-radius: 100%; }
    100% { border-radius: 20%;  }
}
@keyframes oscillate {
    0%   { border-radius: 20%;  }
    50%  { border-radius: 100%; }
    100% { border-radius: 20%;  }
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">Hi</div>
```

Comment: I need it to be linked with a javascript timer so that i can pause / resume the animation, so CSS only is not the solution im looking for :/

Answer (score 1):

One more example of CSS animation which probably better option then javascript:

```css
.circle {
    background: coral;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s ease infinite alternate;
    animation: pulse 1s ease infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(.2);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

For Firefox you will need to add prefixless rule

```
@keyframes pulse {
    from { transform: scale(1); }
    to { transform: scale(.2); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need it to be javascript because i have a timer that has a pause / resume methods

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS3 animation set on infinite. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqmrhg8L/).

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0%, 100% {    -webkit-transform: scale(1);  }
  50%  {    -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0%, 100% {    transform: scale(1);  }
  50%  {    transform: scale(0.2);  }

}
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    border-radius:60px;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be linked with a javascript timer so that i can pause / resume the animation, so CSS only is not the solution im looking for :/ Thanks anyway